# What is the need for "bool" in queries with single must/should/must_not?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch I can use **boolean combination** with Single must/should, is there any meaning to that?

This example with only one **must** inside **bool** works

```
GET /logstash-2021.02.25/_search
{
    "query":
    {
        "bool":
        {
            "must":
            [{
                "match": 
                {
                    "level": "Error"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

In this other example without the "bool" (since there is only one **must**) it doesn't work

```
GET /logstash-2021.02.25/_search
{
    "query":
    {
        "must":
        [{
            "match": 
            {
                "level": "Error"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Second query can be written as `{"query":{"match":{"level":"Error"}}}` (ie without enclosing `match` inside `must`). `must`, `must_not` etc. are occurrence types for `bool` queries, hence must be enclosed within `bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES DSL Query with bool means, Query that matches documents matching boolean combinations of other queries. The bool query maps to the underlying Elasticsearch layer of Lucene's Boolean query which makes the ES more powerful and delightful. It is built using one or more boolean clauses, each clause with a typed occurrence.

Elastic search bool query is a widely used query when it comes to a complex combination of filters. furthermore, ElasticSearch is able to run all the complex queries together in real-time and locate the most suitable results and return them to the user in a very short amount of time using the bool query